# C# Content.ReadAsAsync

Tags: c#, http, post

As a form of study, I'm performing an integration with the Sandbox API of a payment gateway. I am already able to perform the POST for the desired endpoint by passing the information in the Body + Headers. My question would be about using the Content.ReadAsAsync method to get the return of this POST. In response, I get a lot of information about the payment (including a GUID that identifies the transaction identifier).

I'm trying to use Content.ReadAsAsync in the way below but I'm getting a "null" return. Since it's the first time I do something like that, could you give me an idea of ​​how to get the data together?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
 var transactionbuilder = new TransactionBuilder("300", customer, payment);         


            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("//ENDPOINT"); /
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("//HEADER1");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("//HEADER2");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("//RESOURCE", transactionbuilder);
            TransactionResponse exibeResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TransactionResponse>();

            Console.WriteLine(
               $"{exibeResponse.AcquirerTransactionId}\n " +
               $"{exibeResponse.AuthorizationCode}\n" +
               $" {exibeResponse.PaymentId}\n" +
               $" {exibeResponse.ProofOfSale}\n " +
               $"{exibeResponse.ProviderReturnCode} \n" +
               $"{exibeResponse.ProviderReturnMessage} \n" +
               $"{exibeResponse.ReasonCode}\n " +
               $"{exibeResponse.ReasonMessage}\n " +
               $"{exibeResponse.ReceivedDate}\n " +
               $"{exibeResponse.Status}"
               );
```

Comment: Have you tried using `'ReadAsStringAsync` to get the raw contents? Or checked the status code on the response? Maybe the response is not what you expect. Judging from the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpContentExtensions.cs#L255), my guess is that the response is empty.

Comment: Hello @Yogu, as you suggested I used the ReasAsStringAsync and received the expected return. Could you tell me why my first approach did not work?

Thank you in advance for helping me to move forward on this issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know the framework you're using, so I can just guess. You could check if the `Content-Type` header is correct on the response, or you could see if the `TransactionResponse` class has any properties that might complicate deserialization (and remove some of them for testing purposes), or try the (internally used) newtonsoft JSON deserializer on the response text directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share, after the talk with @Yogu I solved it with the option below.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("RESOURCE", transactionbuilder); 
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 

            dynamic formattedContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content); 
            var OrderPaymentId = formattedContent.Payment.PaymentId;
            var OrderInstallments = formattedContent.Payment.Installments;
            var OrderCapturedDate = formattedContent.Payment.CapturedDate;

            Console.WriteLine($"" +
                $"GUID: {OrderPaymentId}\n" +
                $"Quantidade de Parcelas: {OrderInstallments}\n" +
                $"Data de captura: {OrderCapturedDate}");
```